# ASP_0158_:_80004005| Misiing URL

Tags: oracle11g, asp-classic, iis-7, windows-server-2008

When i am trying to login, it is giving me DB unavailable error.

I checked the iis 7 logs in my windows server 2008. It is showing: `ASP_0158_:_80004005| Mising URL`.

I am trying to migrate my classic ASP application from windows server 2003 to windows server 2008 r2 .

I have Oracle 11.2.0.3 installed.

```vbs
sub Open 
    on error resume next 
    Set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    db.Open Application("Connect") 
    'Response.write err.description 
    if err.number <> 0 then 
        db.close 
        Response.Redirect "notapproved.asp?db=unavailable&instance= "
    end if 
end sub
```

Comment: please show some code, are you doing a redirect ?

Comment: sub Open
 on error resume next
 Set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 db.Open Application("Connect")
 'Response.write err.description
 
 if err.number <> 0 then
  db.close
  Response.Redirect "notapproved.asp?db=unavailable&instance= " 
 end if
 
end sub

Comment: You have commented out the `err.description`, move it after the  `if err.number<>0` line  and see what it says.